# How to call a function from inside onStart of Gesture Handler (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-reanimated, react-native-gesture-handler

Every time I try to call a function from inside the onStart of my gesture handler, the app crashes. I've tried to use runOnJS, runOnUI, add 'worklet', but nothing seems to work.

Can someone help me figure out how I can modify my code to fix it?

Here's my code:

```
  const pullingToMatchGestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
    onStart: () => {
      animateShakeValue(); // <----- this crashes my app
    },
    onActive: (event) => {
      const direction = 0;
      const distance = Math.sqrt(
        Math.pow(event.translationX, 2) + Math.pow(event.translationY, 2)
      );
      if (event.translationX > 0 && -event.translationY > 0) {
        direction = Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX < 0 && -event.translationY > 0) {
        direction =
          Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX < 0 && -event.translationY < 0) {
        direction =
          Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      } else if (event.translationX > 0 && -event.translationY < 0) {
        direction =
          2 * Math.PI + Math.atan(-event.translationY / event.translationX);
      }

      let rotationInRad = (rotation.value * Math.PI) / 180;
      rotationInRad = -rotationInRad + Math.PI / 2;
      while (rotationInRad < 0) {
        rotationInRad = rotationInRad + 2 * Math.PI;
      }
      const differenceAngle = rotationInRad - direction;
      if (
        -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) > 0 &&
        -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) < window.width / 5
      )
        pullDistance.value = -distance * Math.cos(differenceAngle) * 2.5;
    },
    onEnd: (event) => {
      pullDistance.value = 0;
    },
  });

  const animateShakeValue = () => {
    const EASING = Easing.elastic(1.5);
    runOnJS(console.log)("animate");

    rotation.value = withSequence(
      // deviate left to start from -ANGLE
      withTiming(-10, { duration: 100 / 2, easing: EASING }),
      // wobble between -ANGLE and ANGLE 7 times
      withRepeat(
        withTiming(10, {
          duration: 100,
          easing: EASING,
        }),
        7,
        true
      ),
      // go back to 0 at the end
      withTiming(0, { duration: 100 / 2, easing: EASING })
    );
  };
```